# How does bearing reliability factor effect the static safety values of a bearing?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, statics, bearings, machine-design, stiffness

I have a SKF 30202 style bearing and i found that the static safety factor of this bearing is 2.76 for a reliability of 90% how does the static safety factor change if my reliabilty was 99%? How can i determine this with which formulas or calculations?

Comment: What does SKF say?

Comment: SKF says 3.88 static safety